# Recyclerview data coming from multiple thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask, retrofit

I have two asynctask which parse website using Jsoup and a retrofit instance which retrive the Json data using website API . Does all this three task continue in parallel or are executed sequentially ? Also i can only set  my recycler adapter when all three task is completed ( 2 asynctask and 1 Retrofit).

How do i know when all the three task is completed (in case if they are executed in parallel) so i can set the adapter of recyclerview ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AsyncTask.execute() then your two Jsoup tasks will be executed one by one in a background thread.

Your retrofit call will start as soon as a thread from retrofit threadpool is free.

Hence these tasks will start in parallel.

To keep a track that all the tasks are complete you can create a common callback method which is being called on success of these tasks.  OnPostExecute of Asynctask call this callback and then onSuccess of Retrofit API call call this callback.

Increase a count variable when u receive the callback.. when count reaches 3.. set the adapter.

> Please note : you will have to consider error handling scenarios.